# Why did the hog riders follow this path?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Considering a situation like this:

[image]

You would think that they would go towards the cannon first, since it's the shortest path there.

Instead apparently they went for the archer tower:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

> Why did my hogs target the archer tower instead of the cannon, which was obviously closer?

This is because the troop's targeting AI has a spec of "random" (actually determined by the attack's timestamp) placed into it.

What this does is that if there are two targets, of similar distance, as you've shown there, the troop may pick one over the other.

You can see this visible, if you were to extract a replay, change its timestamp and play it. This time, you'll see a different outcome as all a replay does is store the times which troop is deployed and not their full path.

---

Another comment to it: You may have calculated the path to the cannon incorrectly; it's a tiny bit closer than you think.

Comment: I may have calculated the path incorrectly or are you sure I have? If so, how?

Comment: @Shoe The closest point to your point of placement along the cannon is its corner, not the point along its edges (since the hog rider is a melted unit) that you have marked.